# Wrapping MPI in boost.python

Tags: python, c++, boost, mpi

I've managed to write wrappers to initialize and finalize the MPI environment using Boost.python, but I'm not sure if everything is properly initialized. I haven't run into any problems yet, but I wanted to see if what I'm doing is somehow incorrect and will cause problems later on or if there is a better way to do this.

I am aware that python does have bindings to MPI (via mpi4py), but this does not serve my needs properly. The simple example below could be replaced by mpi4py, but I don't actually need to initialize the plain MPI environment: I need to initialize a specialized MPI environment (MADNESS/TiledArray), of which there are no python bindings that I can find.

My file structure is as follows:

interface.cxx:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <mpi.h>

void initMPI(int argc, boost::python::list argv){
  char ** argv_ = new char *[argc];
  for(auto i = 0; i < argc; i++){
    std::string str = boost::python::extract<std::string>(argv[i]);
    auto len = str.length();
    argv_[i] = new char[len+1];
    strncpy(argv_[i],&str[0],len);
    argv_[i][len] = '\0'; // Termination character
  }
  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv_);
  for(auto i = 0; i < argc; i++){
    delete [] argv_[i];
  }
  delete [] argv_;
};

void finalizeMPI(){
  MPI_Finalize();
};

void hello(){
  int world_size, rank, name_len;
  std::string name;
  name.reserve(MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_size);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
  MPI_Get_processor_name(&name[0],&name_len);
printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d"
           " out of %d processors\n",
           name.c_str(), rank, world_size);
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mpiinterface){
  boost::python::def("init", initMPI);
  boost::python::def("finalize", finalizeMPI);
  boost::python::def("hello",hello);
};
```

test.py:

```
import sys,os
sys.path.append('/home/dbwy/devel/tests/MPI/boost.python')
import mpiinterface

mpiinterface.init(len(sys.argv),sys.argv)
mpiinterface.hello();
mpiinterface.finalize();
```

When compiled, it does give me the proper output:

```
[dbwy@medusa boost.python]$ mpirun -np 4 python test.py
Hello world from processor medusa.chem.washington.edu, rank 0 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor medusa.chem.washington.edu, rank 3 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor medusa.chem.washington.edu, rank 1 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor medusa.chem.washington.edu, rank 2 out of 4 processors
```

Is it really this easy? Or am I missing something large that is going to be catastrophic later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As virtually all existing MPI implementations nowadays comply with the MPI-2 specification, which was published back in 1998, this whole processing of the arguments list is not needed at all. Starting with MPI-2, one can initialise MPI by calling `MPI_Init(NULL, NULL)`.

And indeed, using MPI is as simple as calling `MPI_Init` **once** at the beginning of your application and `MPI_Finalize` **once** before it exits. If your program is multithreaded, then you should replace `MPI_Init` with [`MPI_Init_thread`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.10/man3/MPI_Init_thread.3.php) and make sure that the MPI library provides support for the desired level of multithreading.

Comment: I was unaware about being able to call `MPI_Init` with `NULL`, that greatly simplifies things! I'm not doing anything multithreaded at the moment (but Id I need to, the MADNESS init will take care of that, I believe)